# Paper-and-dice random loot chart for psionic item powers

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tools, psionics, treasure, tool-recommendation

Where can I find a table of random psionic powers to go with the [random psionic items chart](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Random_Psionic_Items) in the SRD?  For example to determine which powers are imprinted in a power stone found as random treasure?

I know there's at least one [random treasure generator](http://donjon.bin.sh/d20/treasure/) online, but our GM wants to use pen & paper (and dice) instead of a random generator. The SRD seems to have treasure charts for psionics like for other types of items, but they don't get down to the level of which power (like the current charts do for which spell in on a scroll or wand, for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Expanded Psionics Handbook "helpfully" describes the procedure for determining number and levels of Powers in a Powerstone using those tables, and then says (p. 168):

> […] then choose the specific power of a given level from those described in Chapter 5. You can pick a desired power or determine the power randomly.

I guess on the plus side, the DM is empowered by the rules to select them non-randomly. When that's not what you want though, such as in your DM's situation, the rules leave you to roll your own random-selection process.

At the beginning of Chapter 5, the powers are listed by level for psions, wilders, and psychic warriors, and by discipline. Unlike the old AD&D spell lists, these aren't numbered for easy random determination. But you can take that old-school methodology as inspiration, and if you have a copy of the book (or more likely for this purpose, a photocopy of the relevant pages), your DM can pencil in numbers to turn the list into a numbered table or set of tables that can be rolled on with whatever dice give the nearest useful range and a flat distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [loot generator](http://donjon.bin.sh/d20/treasure/index.cgi) to do so.  Just tick the ticky box for psionics.

Comment: Thanks, I found that but our GM wants to use pen & paper (and dice) instead of a random generator.  The SRD seems to have treasure charts for psionics like for other types of items, but they don't get down to the level of which power (like the current charts do for which spell in on a scroll or wand, for example)

Comment: @PurpleVermont You should put that restriction into your question.

Comment: @KRyan, well I did ask for a chart, not a generator.  I'll add it though.

Comment: You can always print out the resulting loot. I know I've done it with many online generators.